# Rcpp import list / dataframe from R with a large number of variable

Tags: r, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp programming and I cannot figure out a very basic thing.

I am trying to import an large list from R to c++. I am using Rcpp. The list I have contains about 400,000 rows and 50 columns. I am recreating a smaller version of it here for your reference.

```
df1 = data.frame(Variable1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1),Variable2=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,11),
             Variable3 = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1),
             Variable4=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
             Variable5=c(20,-2,-5,10,30,2,1,.5,50,-1,60))
```

This is a dataframe object. I know from this post ([how many vectors can be added in DataFrame::create( vec1, vec2 ... )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371543/how-many-vectors-can-be-added-in-dataframecreate-vec1-vec2)) that you can only import dataframe objects in Rcpp with 20 columns. You could also have as many columns as you want from Kevin Ushey's post here ([how many vectors can be added in DataFrame::create( vec1, vec2 ... )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371543/how-many-vectors-can-be-added-in-dataframecreate-vec1-vec2)). I would prefer to not use the dataframe route since I need to write a fairly complicated function.

My confusion comes from the following: when I use

```
typeof(df1)
```

R tells me that this is a list object.

What would be the best way to import this data in Rcpp? Could someone point me to a source/ show me a replica code that I might be able to use for my dataset (please note my dataset has 50 columns)?

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The limitation on 20 columns is relevant for *creating* DataFrames within C++. You can use such wide DataFrames as argument without problems.

Comment: In that case, would I simply call the object as a Rcpp::list? @RalfStubner

Comment: @Prometheus `Rcpp::DataFrame`. [Here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/modifying-a-data-frame/) is a related Rcpp Gallery post.

Comment: Thanks @duckmayr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RalfStubner and @duckmayr mentioned, you may have been misreading the *existing restrictions on construction*.  There are no restrictions on *accepting existing data frame objects*.

To illustrate, here is a not entirely sensible example of a 500 column `data.frame` (which, for simplicity, we assume to contain only numeric vectors) where we sum up all elements in the first row.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double extractFromBigDataFrame(Rcpp::DataFrame d, bool verbose=false) {
  int n = d.length();
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // we are making a simplifying assumption here that each column is numeric
    Rcpp::NumericVector x = d[i];
    double elem = x[0];
    sum += elem;
    if (verbose) print(x);
  }
  return sum;
}

/*** R
m <- matrix(1:1000, 2, 500)
d <- as.data.frame(m)
extractFromBigDataFrame(d)
rowSums(m)  # comparison
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/so54563983.cpp")

R> m <- matrix(1:1000, 2, 500)

R> d <- as.data.frame(m)

R> extractFromBigDataFrame(d)
[1] 250000

R> rowSums(m)  # comparison
[1] 250000 250500
R>
```